# Test tasks missing from rake: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'test:units'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake, testunit

I created a Rails 4 app recently and for some reason my rake tasks don't include `test`. Here's some console action to demonstrate the problem:

```
> rake test:units
    rake aborted!
    Don't know how to build task 'test:units'
    /Users/clozach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@hoverfly/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /Users/clozach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@hoverfly/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Fail. :(

```
> rake test
>
```

No output. :(

```
> rake -T --all | grep test
    rake db:test:clone                      # 
    rake db:test:clone_schema               # 
    rake db:test:clone_structure            # 
    rake db:test:deprecated                 # 
    rake db:test:load                       # 
    rake db:test:load_schema                # 
    rake db:test:load_structure             # 
    rake db:test:prepare                    # 
    rake db:test:purge                      # 
    rake log:clear                          # Truncates all *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (specify which logs with LOGS=test,development)
    rake tmp/cache/assets/test              #
```

No `test` tasks at all! :'(

Any idea why this is the case, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look into `config/application.rb` whether the testing framework is actually required there. At the very top, there should be

```
require "rails/all"
```

Depending on your setup, you might have each individual component required separately. Make sure that `test_unit` is among them.

```
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Obvious in retrospect, but so frustrating while unsolved! Thank you thank you thank you. :)